# Google sheets -> Data validation -> Custom formula -> How to refer to the currently validated input

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know how to put in validation rules that involve checking values of other cells,
but how can I compare freshly entered data against other cell values?
For example if I would like to limit data entry to:
"Only numbers that are smaller or equal to cell value A1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=(B1<=A1)*(ISNUMBER(B1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, to put your answer in an even simpler context: You stated that I can refer to the active cell in the formula and in that case not the old, but the tested new value would be taken into consideration!
I have tired that originally and did not work for some reason, but I think my error was different, because this time it worked properly for all scenarios!!
For example: =and(I2<>"";isnumber(J2);J2<=H2)